# Tooltip with close button

Tags: jquery-ui, button, tooltip

How can I get tooltip which look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fZBI.jpg
I think so I can get this using jquery UI. But I can't write the code. I want the tooltip which show this, what is in .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) ? :)
Its really nice :)

**EDIT**

If you want to use jQuery UI then look at this: 
http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style